# having a single before pseudo selector in CSS to display information about multiple elements in a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to display data information for the span elements that are appearing in a line next to the line itself and I am able to achieve this using the ::before pseudo selector.

But the problem with this is, If I wanted display information about two separate elements in the same line, their ::before selectors are overlapping each other. And even If I could separate them I am wondering if there would be any other reliable way to show this kind of information (data of numerous html elements that might occur on a line) for each line on a **single** element (so that when I hover on the element it would show the gathered information for that line.

For example:

```html
<p> "Neque porro quisquam est <span data-info="1">qui</span> dolorem <span data-info="2">ipsum</span> quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>
```

assuming this text above is single line, I am looking to somehow dynamically create an element before the line that would show the list of data("info") on this line, which is '"1", "2"'.

One way of doing this that comes to my mind is to wrap each line in a new html element and have that html element gather that information about it's content in itself, and display the ::before only for that element, though I am not even sure if that is even possible / feasible.

I am open to a different kind of a solution as well, don't have to use ::before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show 'data-info' data in a different html element dynamically? If I understood you correctly, you can't achieve this with CSS.

If 'data-info' information is static (can you use it in the content property of the ::before pseudo-element?) then there might be a away of doing this with CSS only.